# Will this code have Time Complexity O(n^5) or O(n^3) or anything else?

Tags: time-complexity

I am having problem in identifying the time complexity of this nested loop code. Some of my friends are saying O(n^3) and O(n^5).

```
sum = 0;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)

        for(int j=0; j<i*i; j++)

                for(int k=0; k<j; k++)

                       sum++;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28i%3D0%29%5E%28n-1%29%28+sum_%28j%3D0%29%5E%28i%5E2+-+1%29%28+sum_%28k%3D0%29%5E%28j-1%29+1%29%29) gives the total count of increments to `sum` as

```
sum_(i=0)^(n-1)( sum_(j=0)^(i^2 - 1)( sum_(k=0)^(j-1) 1))
= 1/20 (n - 2) (n - 1) n (n + 1) (2 n - 1)
= n^5/10 - n^4/4 + n^2/4 - n/10
```

which is in θ(n^5).

Comment: Hm then yours is probably right, but I don't understand why it would by a higher than the fourth power. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: For the innermost loop, you get the classic "naive O(N^2) sorting" situation, where we know that running `for (a=0; a<n; ++a) for(b = 0; b<a; ++b)` results in O(n^2). Assume `n` is simply a substitution for `i*i` and you get `for (a=0; a<i*i; ++a) for(b = 0; b<a; ++b)`, which should still give you O(n^2) = O(i^4) iterations. Or, put more abstract, as you already did: The one loop going to N^2 will also make its child quadratic on average.

Answer (score 0):

I would say time complexity is about `N * (N*N)/2 * N/2`. Combined it would be `O(N^4)`.

Edit: it's `O(N^5)`because the inner loop is squared by the middle loop!

But don't take my word for it. For these kind of questions, why don't you run a few examples of your code with different `N` and compare the `sum`s, you will figure out what the time-complexity is soon enough.

Comment: Why (N/2) for the innermost loop? for k=0 to j I would expect it to be in the order of N^2.

Comment: Hm now I see I think, because the middle loop is squared,  the innerloop would also be squared